# Are you ready to play me?

Tags: riddle

I have a color, I have a name,

You love to play me, if you are game.

If I am under age, you might have to send me back,

When I am just the right age, you will be a happy chap.

But if I am too old, well, then that's too bad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are:

> Blackjack. Your color is black, your name is Jack, you're a game. If you're "under age" (9, 10, 11, etc.) I'm going to go back for more cards. If you're just the right age (21), I'm psyched! And if you're older, I just lost this round!

Comment: This fits some lines well, but I'm not sure about "you might have to send me back". Also, the author would be describing your hand and not the game in the last three lines, so he'd say "if you are...age" instead of "I am...age".

Comment: It could be referring to 21 being the age at which somebody can go into a casino in the United States.

Comment: @Roland, That is the right answer.  The last 3 lines describe the hand - below 21, at 21 and over 21.  My intended interpretation is you *might* lose if your hand is below 21 (thus, "send me back").  What I didn't mention is you may also win even when you hand is below 21.

Comment: "Hm .. games that go up to 18 .." -Me